# how to pass queryset or kwarg to RangeFilter class in Django filters

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

I'm working on a Django-driven website which uses django-filters and, specifically, RangeFilter to show price diapason of the real estate properties and visualize it as a slider on search form.

My queryset is initially formed in the PropertyListView as a list of objects with a certain status (sale or rent), and then it is being passed to the filter, PropertyFilter.

The PropertyFilter uses several other classes to construct corresponding widgets, such as slider for the price:

```
class PropertyFilter(FilterSet):
    price = PriceFilter()
    ...


class PriceFilter(RangeFilter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        values = [p.price for p in Property.objects.all()]
        min_value = min(values)
        max_value = max(values)
        self.extra['widget'] = CustomRangeWidget(attrs={'label':_('Price, €'),'data-range_min':min_value,'data-range_max':max_value})
```

The problem is that the PriceFilter does not "know", which objects are in the queryset, and takes the price diapason from the full list of objects. This results in awkward slider, whose diapason is too wide, from 600 to 300,000 euro, which is irrelevant.

I want to make the PriceFilter to get prices from the queryset. How it is possible to do it? I've tried to use queryset directly inside this filter, to pass the queryset into it, or to pass the status as a kwarg parameter, but every time I got an error.

Please help me, I'm stuck on it.

Answer (score 1):

you can modify the `PriceFilter` class to accept the queryset and use it to determine the price range

```
class PriceFilter(RangeFilter):
    def __init__(self, queryset=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if queryset is not None:
            values = [p.price for p in queryset]
            min_value = min(values) if values else 0
            max_value = max(values) if values else 0
            self.extra['widget'] = CustomRangeWidget(attrs={'label': _('Price, €'), 'data-range_min': min_value, 'data-range_max': max_value})
        else:
            self.extra['widget'] = CustomRangeWidget(attrs={'label': _('Price, €'), 'data-range_min': 0, 'data-range_max': 0})
```

then you would pass the queryset from your `PropertyListView` to the `PropertyFilter` and subsequently to the `PriceFilter`:

```
class PropertyFilter(FilterSet):
    price = PriceFilter(queryset=Property.objects.none()) # initialize with an empty queryset
    def __init__(self, data=None, queryset=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if queryset is not None:
            self.price = PriceFilter(queryset=queryset, *args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(data, queryset, *args, **kwargs)
    # other filters

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ['price', ...]
```

and now in your `PropertyListView` you can pass the queryset to the `PropertyFilter`:

```
class PropertyListView(ListView):
    model = Property

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Property.objects.filter(status='your_status_goes_here')
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        property_filter = PropertyFilter(data=self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        context['filter'] = property_filter
        return context
```

this way the `PriceFilter` will consider only the prices from the filtered queryset ensuring that the slider reflects the appropriate price range.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, Kiarash! I thought I've already tried this approach, but I could do something wrong. Now I will try another time, exactly by your scheme, and will report if it works.

Comment: You approach works! The PriceFilter now gets queryset from the PropertyFilter. But now I need the PropertyFilter to get the queryset from PropertyListView instead of generate it. Can you advise me how to do it? I'm trying, but still get an error (currently that PropertyFilter.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'queryset').

Comment: By logic, PropertyFiltes should get the queryset from the PropertyListView. But I cannot figure out how to access it. When I write price = PriceFilter(queryset=self.kwargs['queryset']), I get an error "name 'self' is not defined". Please help!

Comment: for that you should modify the ```PropertyFilter``` class to accept the ```queryset``` from the ```PropertyListView``` and pass it to the ```PriceFilter``` class

Comment: I have edited the answer, I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, Kiarash! Your advice seems to work! Just correct one error and one typo. "self.filters['price']" should be "self.price", and capitalize "property" in  "property.objects.filter" ("Property.objects.filter"). Thank you very much!

Comment: Kiarash, one more question. The filters are context aware now, but the form is not rendered on the page. Before I declared filterset in my get_queryset method (self.filterset = PropertyFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=queryset)) and passed its form in the get_context: context['form'] = self.filterset.form. Now it doesn't work since I have no self.filterset. How can I display the filter form on the page?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. 
thanks for corrections, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Kiarash, I need your advice again. If I hardcode the variable price in my PropertyFilter like this: price = PriceFilter(queryset=Property.objects.filter(status='sale')), everything goes well, the PriceFilter sees the queryset and displays correct price diapazon. But when I try to override the price in the __init__ method (below), the PriceFilter doesn't see it.
    def __init__(self, data=None, queryset=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.price = PriceFilter(queryset=queryset, *args, **kwargs
        super().__init__(data, queryset, *args, **kwargs) 

However, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, Kiarash, your code doesn't work quite well. The filter works good, but the form does not display right price diapason. Looks like the PriceFilter is initialized before it is called by PropertyFilter, on server (python manage.py runserver) start, with empty queryset. When it is called, the arguments are not being overrode.